# Pole - zero cancellation for frequency compensation

Tags: analog, frequency-response

i am now designing an opamp used for feedback network and taking frequency compensation to help phase margin by killing the big "mirror pole" at node E (the left circuit) using R-C topology (the right circuit), but I cant write the transfer function to prove it. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you so much.[image: Schematic of frequency compensation technique]

Comment: Got a simulator? Prove it after you write some measureable test specs

Comment: Without showing what you have done so far, there's no way anyone can point out where you did wrong.